# SharePoint Change FavIcon modern view Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

My scenario - Classic view shows favicon which I have changed in my custom master page which is the brand logo which is working fine. but if I exit classic view it change the favicon to SharePoint default favicon. The default Logo is only showing in Librarys.

Comment: Can you show us which favicon you are talking about? Please attach screenshots to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Master pages is a technology that only targets classic UI. Modern UI does not support master pages. Therefore the behaviour you described is expected.

There is no way for your master page to be applied to the modern UI.

However, if you create a Custom Extension using SharePoint Framework, you can [inject the following code to change favicon dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically):

```
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel~='icon']");
if (!link) {
    link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'icon';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}
link.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
```

**Sample**

[image]